# How does a semaphore release from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

From what I know a thread can release on a semaphore without first acquiring a lock with `WaitOne`.

So, if we have threads A, B and C and a semaphore, A and B call `WaitOne`, get a lock and start doing their business.

Along comes thread C and just calls `Release` on the semaphore.

This should increment the semaphore's count by 1. Does this mean the semaphore will terminate either A or B or just allow a third thread to acquire a lock and have 3 threads in its pool, even if the maximum was 2?

Comment: The semaphore isn't an active object; it doesn't govern the running of any code. It's the programmer's responsibility to use it in a way that makes sense. If that means adding mutual exclusion, that's a separate problem -- a simple counting semaphore doesn't take care of that. Thread C, with its rogue releasing of a resource it didn't own, is buggy. Monitors are a higher-level abstraction that don't have this issue, which is why raw semaphores in .NET code are fairly rare.For simpler scenarios, when only thread-safe counters are needed, there's `Interlocked`.

Comment: Before you execute the threads you reset the two semaphores.  Then inside the threads at the end you set the semaphores.  So C does nothing except waits until the two semaphores are set.

Comment: @jdweng, let's for a moment assume I'm not following good programming practices in an effort to supply a theoretical scenario for a specific question on an Internet site about such things.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, does that mean I am correct in my assumptions in the question or not?

Comment: Yes, but as is usual with such things, the best way to convince yourself is to make a small toy application that demonstrates the problem (tools like LINQPad make this really easy). I think that's better than the comments of any random person on the internet (certainly more insightful). While showing threading issues can sometimes be tricky (and the absence of any downright impossible sometimes), for demonstration purposes chucking in a few `.Sleep`s where necessary usually does the trick.

Comment: Semaphores are static objects that are designed to work between threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);
```

It means that the semaphore at this moment of time has only 2 executions slots, but you have to keep in mind that it is only the **initial number** of executions slots (for requests to be granted concurrently).

So, if we will spawn A,B,C thread into a semaphore with 2 executions slots the first two threads will be executed and the C thread will be queued until someone else in the code will signal the semaphore it is OK to add one more execution slot.

When someone will say its OK to execute the next thread in the queue, the C will be executed regardless to the others thread.

---

### Some technical example:

(As I saw in @dmitri-nesteruk's course)

The total number of **available** executions slots is being represented by `CurrentCount`.

Each time a thread wanted to be executed it asks the semaphore if it has an available execution slot (with `CurrentCount > 0`), if true - feel free to get yourself executed, if not get inside the queue.

What makes the semaphore so confusing is the fact that `CurrentCount` value can be either decreased or increased.

- Its decreases by one each time the `Wait()` has been called by a
  thread, which means that there is one less available execution slot
  and the a thread is being executed.
- Its increases by one (or more) each time the `Release(1)` has been
  called somewhere else in the code, which means that there is one more
  available execution slot so the first thread in the semaphore inside
  **queue** is being executed (it won't terminate the others).

In this example the we spawn 3 threads, but the only first two will be executed until someone will say to the semaphore that he can release another execution slot by increasing the `CurrentCount` with `Release(1)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Spawning task: {Task.CurrentId}");
        semaphore.Wait(); //CurrentCount--
        Console.WriteLine($"Executing task: {Task.CurrentId}");
    });
}


while (semaphore.CurrentCount <= 2)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Key pressed");
    semaphore.Release(1); //CurrentCount++
}
```

### The Output:

```
Spawning task: A
Spawning task: B
Spawning task: C
Executing task: A
Executing task: B
.....
Key pressed
Executing task: C
```

Comment: your answer is nice 'n' all but the key point that answered my question was given in a comment by Jeroen Mostert, which was "a semaphore is not an active object" i.e. a semaphore does nothing to govern the execution of code, it's just a simple synchronizing construct that lets things past it but what they do after that - it don't care. Because initially I thought it governed the execution of any threads it passed, like a Monitor (in the sense that the monitor very much cares what happens with the thread that enters it, because it needs to release it).

Comment: @ShaharShokrani, that is typical of most synchronization objects in most programming languages and libraries:  They only function as gates that prevent a thread from passing until some condition has been met.  In order to protect a data structure from corruption, the programmer must set up a gate, and then it becomes the programmer's responsibility to ensure that no code ever modifies the data except after it has passed the gate.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a semaphore as a special case of a blocking queue:  The semaphore's "count" is the number of items that are in the queue, but the items themselves contain no information.  Just as any thread is allowed put an item into a blocking queue, and any thread is allowed to take an item out, so any thread can increment or decrement the count of a semaphore.